# Log-transform independent variables in a linear model

Tags: regression, linear-model, logarithm

I have a linear model where some independent variables are probabilities (such as word predictability) and some are integers which are greater than 1 (such as years of experience). However, for all of the variables it makes more sense to consider proportional changes rather than linear changes.

For example, if my model is $y = a + b + c$, I know I can't just change it to $y = \log(a) + \log(b) + \log(c)$, since then I'd be multiplying the variables instead of adding them.

Is there a standard way to do this transformation, or will it always be specific to different situations?